# NSDateComponents not printing accurate day/month/year times

Tags: objective-c, nsdatecomponents

I'm using NSDateComponents to get each day, month, year, hour, minute, etc separately but day, month, year and seconds are not accurate with 2017-11-08 1:00:00....Does anybody know what I'm missing?

```
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
        NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2017-11-08 1:00:00"];
        NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:date];
        NSInteger day = [components day];
        NSInteger month = [components month];
        NSInteger year = [components year];
        NSInteger hour = [components hour];
        NSInteger minute = [components minute];
        NSInteger second = [components second];
        NSLog(@"day: %ld",(long)day);
        NSLog(@"month: %ld",(long)month);
        NSLog(@"year: %ld",(long)year);
        NSLog(@"hour: %ld",(long)hour);
        NSLog(@"minute: %ld",(long)minute);
        NSLog(@"second: %ld",(long)second);
```

Output:

```
        day: 2147483647
        month: 2147483647
        year: 2147483647
        hour: 1
        minute: 0
        second: 2147483647
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're only getting the hour and minute, because that's all you're asking for. If you actually ask for the day, month, year, and second, you'll get them:

```
NSCalendarUnit units = NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear |
                       NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute | NSCalendarUnitSecond;
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate:date];
```